# jquery :contains selector in child window

Tags: jquery

I have a child window that I am trying to use jquery :contains selector, but it does not work.

```
var child = window.open("index.html", null);
child.document.close();//I saw somewhere this was necessary...
$(child.document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout( function() { // necessary to wait a few seconds
        console.log($('.navigation .option:nth-child(4)', child.document).length);
        console.log($('.navigation .option:contains("Item4")', child.document).length);
    }, 5000);
});
```

The :nth-child correctly returns: "Item4".  The second fails to find.  The HTML is:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="option">Item1</div>
    <div class="option">Item2</div>
    <div class="option">Item3</div>
    <div class="option">Item4</div>
</div>
```

In a normal window, the :contains selector works - no problem.  It seems that jquery cannot handle :contains in a child window.  Is this true?

Comment: I've got a feeling this won't work: `$(child.document).ready(function() {` Try this: `$.call(child, function(){`

Comment: I think you're not actually waiting for the _child's_ ready but rather for the _parent's_ ready

Comment: `:contains` works perfectly within a child window, at least there's no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: I can look into the 'ready', but I don't think that is the problem.  The :nth-child selector works.

Comment: Are you testing in IEx or in a modern browser?

Comment: I am testing in chrome.  Incidentally, this works:
console.log($(childWindow.document).contents().find('.navigation .option:contains("Item4")').length);

Comment: Tested in JSfiddle. You are actually waiting for the parent's ready + 5 seconds

Comment: Injecting jQuery into the other window and using it will work: `childWindow.$ = $; childWindow.$(...`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, can you post your fiddle, or provide a little more detail on your solution, e.g. waiting for child window?  I like the childWindow.$ approach, but I'm not quite connecting your dots...

Comment: Ouch - `child.$ = $` won't do because jQuery remembers its "correct" `document`.